# Remove and restore options from select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have html:

```
<select id="sel">
    <option value="1">aaa</option>
    <option value="2">bbb</option>
    <option value="3">ccc</option>
    <option value="4">ddd</option>
    <option value="5">eee</option>
    <option value="6">fff</option>
    <option value="7">ggg</option>
</select>

<button id="remove">remove</button>
<button id="restore">restore</button>
```

and javascript:

```
function rand(){
return Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 1;
}

function deleteRandom(){

$.each([rand(), rand(), rand()], function( index, value ) {
  $("#sel option[value=" + value + "]").remove();
    //here should be saved...
});

}

function restore(){
 //this function should restore #sel
}

$("#remove").click(function(){
   deleteRandom();
})

$("#restore").click(function(){
   restore();
})
```

LIVE DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/g4Q8B/

How is the best method for save remove option from select? I dont want use hide, display:none etc, because this not working in all browsers.
I dont want also use disabled.

I want remove this, and next or previous save all options from select. Maybe i should save all select#sel, but how?

Comment: .remove() returns the DOM element being removed. store it somewhere, and then you can stuff it back into the select when restore time comes up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best approach is store a clone of the options on page load. Then clone that clone to restore, so you always keep the first clone as the cache.

```
var $options=$('#sel option').clone();

function restore(){
 $('#sel').html( $options.clone()) 
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g4Q8B/3/)**</kbd>

Now if you want to do any filtering of options, can do it on the cache also, you always have the full set stored

```
$('#filtered').click(function(){
    /* only options with value > 3*/
    var opts=$options.clone().filter(function(){
       return this.value > 3; 
    })
    $('#sel').html(opts)    
})
```